# Using a while loop with SQL cursors?

Tags: sql, t-sql, if-statement, while-loop, ssms

I am creating an sql script , I have 2 cursors to loop through data a table cursor and a company cursor .
I am having issues putting the company cursor together using while loops to copy data into the schema
I need to answer the below questions using an If Statement

Does the table have a companyID column? an if statement checking for company id
if yes then copy data based on companyID in cursor

I have a @firstLoop declared

Here is my cursor specific code

```
DECLARE @firstLoop BIT
SET @firstLoop = true

----------- Cursor specific code starts here ------------
-- company cursor
declare copyCompanyDataCursor CURSOR fast_forward FOR
SELECT ID from #CompanyIDs;

open copyCompanyDataCursor
fetch next from copyCompanyDataCursor into @Company_Id;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN

        declare @processorder int;
        declare @tablename varchar(500);
        -- table cursor

        declare copyTableDataCursor CURSOR fast_forward FOR
        SELECT processorder,tablename from #TableList4 order by processorder;

        open copyTableDataCursor
        fetch next from copyTableDataCursor into @processorder, @tablename;

        while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
        BEGIN
            SET IDENTITY_INSERT [c365online_script1.dbo.tCompany] OFF

            -- Does the table have a companyID column? if statement checking for company id

            -- if yes then copy data based on companyID in cursor

            -- if no check if this is the first time through company loop and copy all data
            -- if @firstloop company exists look at information schema

                    -- insert into c365online_script1.dbo.tCompany(selec
                    EXEC('INSERT ' + @Destination_Database_Name + '.dbo.' + @tablename + ' SELECT * FROM ' + @Source_Database_Name + '.dbo.' + @tablename + ')')

                    -- company logic


            SET IDENTITY_INSERT [c365online_script1.dbo.tCompany] ON

            FETCH NEXT FROM copyTableDataCursor into @processorder,@tablename;
        END

        close copyTableDataCursor;
        Deallocate copyTableDataCursor;

--INSERT INTO c365online_script1.dbo.tCompany
--SELECT *
--FROM production2.tCompany
--WHERE ISNULL(CompanyID, 0) = 0  -- copy all data where id is equal to zero
--@Destination_Database_Name

--      
        --EXEC(INSERT  + @Destination_Database_Name + '.dbo.' + @tablename + ' SELECT * FROM ' + @Source_Database_Name + '.dbo.' + @tablename + ' WHERE ' + @Source_Database_Name + '.dbo.' + @tablename + '.CompanyID = ' + @Company_Id + ')'      
        SET @firstLoop = false;
        FETCH NEXT FROM copyCompanyDataCursor into @Company_Id;
    END
CLOSE copyCompanyDataCursor;
DEALLOCATE copyCompanyDataCursor;
```

Comment: er, what exactly is the point of all of this?  If you're actually trying to duplicate a schema there are almost certainly built-in options...

Comment: The purpose is to reduce the size of the db by producing a script that you can use to generate a scaled down db by selecting only a few companies that are needed at a given time.The schema is already copied into an empty database I now need to populate it.

Comment: ...I'd put the relevant tables that would be considered for this into their own schema honestly, if you don't duplicate all tables.  There should be scripts generateable by default that'll duplicate schema tables.  And potentially for table contents as well... maybe.  _Why_ are you duplicating the DB this way?  Note that this won't actually reduce the size of the main DB, as you'll still have all the original data.

Comment: Ive been set this task and been specifically told to do it this way

Comment: The database would be smaller as you would specify a company ID at the beginning of the script and wouldn't be creating the whole db.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you replace both the CURSORS with while loop.

CURSORS in SQL Server cost performance very badly instead replacing them with temporary table with While loop will certainly boost the performance and an easier type of coding you will have to write.

For articles about SQL Server please check the below link
[SQL Server real time articles](http://borngeek.in/)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion although I have not made the judgement on using cursors that decision has been made higher up.I have been told to use them but will suggest using while loops.

Comment: uh, he's technically already using a `while` loop to drive the cursors...  You're right that cursors tend to have a performance penalty compared to actual set-based processing... however, the  current procedure seems to require some form of RBAR processing, which is probably going to be _more_ intensive than using a cursor.  Also, cursors don't seem to be mentioned in that link... among other problems

Comment: I would disagree, since it totally depends on the scenario. It is not always a good idea to load data to the `tempdb`. So, you cannot generalize the answer. It always depends on ones scenario, they should test both approaches and go with the one performing better in their case.